# Регулярное выражение для поиска телефона, исключая цену (поиск по условию)

Tags: регулярные-выражения

В объявлениях кроме номеров телефонов часто встречаются цены. Но цены на автомобили, недвижимость и т.п. зело велики.

Вот кусок объявления

> Цена 3 047 500 руб, экв. 265 000 $,Цена за м.кв. 1 286 $, 8(903) 169-4197

Выражение "\d[\d-() ]{6,}" находит и цены, и телефоны.
Поэтому вопрос. Что добавить в выражение, чтобы функция не обращала внимание на группу цифр, позади которой есть "***пробел и руб** или есть **пробел и знак доллара $**, или если перед группой цифр есть **пробел и слово цена** или слово **экв.**"*?

Comment: Если формат телефонных номеров одинаков, то можно к нему привязаться жестко:

    \d\(\d{3}\)\s?\d{3}-\d{4}

Comment: Нет, давайте без "если". В том-то и дело, что цены и телефоны могут быть разных форматов и в разных местах объявления. Если был формат телефонов конкретный, я бы не указывал те условия, что выделены жирным.

Comment: поиск телефона - не проблема, нужно соблюсти указанные условия

Comment: @Akella225, ясно. Тогда ответ @VenZell, вас должен полностью устроить.

Answer (score 1):

```
~цена\s*(\d[\d\s()-]++)|(?P<phone>\d[\d\s()-]++)(?!(?:\s*руб|\s*экв|\s*\$))~iu
```

---

```
?P<phone> = назначаем группе имя phone

(\d[\d\s()-]++)

- начинается с цифры
- после нее идет максимально длинная последовательность из
-- цифр, пробельных символов, скобок и дефиса

(?!(?:\s*руб|\s*экв|\s*\$))
- за предыдущим выражением нет следующего:
-- пробельных символов и (руб), пробельных символов и (экв), пробельных символов и $
```

**[Посмотреть пример работы](http://regex101.com/r/cH6xN4/4)**

**Update:** исключил группу цифр, перед которыми идет (цена) и пробельные символы.

Все номера телефонов, удовлетворяющие заданному условию, находятся в именованной группе **phone**